# NULL vs. `infinity` in PostgreSQL range types

Tags: postgresql, null, range, postgresql-9.2, infinity

What is the meaning of 'infinity' in PostgreSQL range types? Is there any difference between specifying `infinity` or `-infinity` as a bound, or `NULL`? I.e. is `infinity` an explicit form of specifying that the range bound is infinite, whereas `NULL` would implicit specify an infinite bound range?

See the following examples:

```
SELECT tstzrange('-infinity','infinity') && tstzrange(NULL, NULL);
 ?column?
----------
 t

SELECT tstzrange('2013-01-01 00:00:00+01', '2013-02-01 00:00:00+01')
    && tstzrange(NULL, '2013-03-01 00:00:00+01');
 ?column?
----------
 t

SELECT tstzrange('2013-01-01 00:00:00+01', '2013-02-01 00:00:00+01')
    && tstzrange('-infinity', '2013-03-01 00:00:00+01');
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: See this later, better explanation:

- [Why does PostgreSQL consider NULL boundaries in range types to be distinct from infinite boundaries when they're functionally equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610158/why-does-postgresql-consider-null-boundaries-in-range-types-to-be-distinct-from/67612325#67612325)

---

`NULL` does the same thing for the [overlap operator **`&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) as `-infinity` or `infinity`, respectively. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT):

> Using NULL for either bound causes the range to be unbounded on that side.

But as *value*, `NULL` is still distinct from `'infinity'`!

```
SELECT tstzrange('-infinity','infinity') = tstzrange(NULL, NULL);
```

Returns `FALSE` (not `NULL`, mind you!).

More in this [**SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/74859).

Comment: How tests #4 and #6 are true if `SELECT tstzrange('-infinity','infinity') <@ tstzrange(NULL, NULL);` eg '[-infinity,infinity]' is inside '[,)'?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: That's a very good question. I have no good explanation. I don't think there *is* a good explanation other than that's the least awkward arrangement with all the corner cases arising from the mix of "unbounded" and `infinity` in ranges.