# Why `infinity` is not contained by range?

Tags: postgresql, range

I have range which upper bound is infinity.

Why infinity is not contained by this range?

I expect that this returns true:

```
=> select '[2019-01-02, infinity]'::daterange @> 'infinity'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

because:

```
=> select 'infinity'::date = 'infinity'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103608 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578050

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the bug is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INFINITE) says:

> Also, some element types have a notion of “infinity”, but that is just another value so far as the range type mechanisms are concerned. For example, in timestamp ranges, `[today,]` means the same thing as `[today,)`. But `[today,infinity]` means something different from `[today,infinity)` — the latter excludes the special timestamp value `infinity`.

That seems to flatly contradict your observations, because

```
SELECT 'infinity'::date;
   date   
----------
 infinity
(1 row)
```

The explanation for this behavior is that PostgreSQL converts ranges of “discrete” types (`date` and the `integer` types) into their “canonical” representation:

```
SELECT '[2010-01-01,2010-02-28]'::daterange;
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2010-01-01,2010-03-01)
(1 row)
```

This is what happened in your example: PostgreSQL adds 1 to `infinity` (which doesn't change the value) and converts the inclusive upper bound to an exclusive upper bound.

Now this is arguably not the correct behavior, because now `infinity` is not part of the interval any more. I have sent in a patch for that, and it got fixed with [commit e6feef571a](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e6feef571a016c9dac52a01aebad484768eb5c68).

Answer (score 1):

```
select '[2019-01-02, infinity]'::daterange;
+-------------------------------------------+
| daterange                                 |
|-------------------------------------------|
| DateRange('2019-01-02', 'infinity', '[)') |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

`[)` means that the right border is excluded.

> But note that these infinite values are never values of the range's element type, and can never be part of the range.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

**Edit**

Also note this:

```
select '[2019-01-01, 2019-01-31]'::daterange;         
+---------------------------------------------+
| daterange                                   |
|---------------------------------------------|
| DateRange('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '[)') |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The inclusive range is translated to an exclusive range one day later. How should this be done for infinity?

Comment: That seems at odds from the next paragraph, but I'm probably missing something here: *"But [today,infinity] means something different from [today,infinity) — the latter excludes the special timestamp value infinity."* In essense `[today, infinity]` noted here in the documentation is not possible because the previous paragraph quoted in this answer states as much.

Comment: Maybe an inconsistent wording in the documentation.

Comment: @LutzHorn: To my mind the `infinity` despite on it is inclusive or exclusive should be part of the range. eg: [7,infinity) @> infinity should be TRUE, [7,infinity] @> infinity should be TRUE. `infinity` is special thus should be handled specially

Comment: @LutzHorn: look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907513/4632019) solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `ilmari`.

For those who is looking the working solution for `select '[2019-01-02, infinity]'::daterange @> 'infinity'::date;` that is: do not use `infinity` as a bound, use an unbounded range:

```
> select '[2019-01-02,)'::daterange @> 'infinity'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

> select '[2019-01-02,]'::daterange @> 'infinity'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```